# How to unlock bootloader of my vivo v20 pro or how to root it

Tags: rooting, custom-roms, bootloader-lock, android-13, vivo

how to unlock bootloader on my vivo v20 so that i can compile and install a new rom. Cause I find no websites to download custom rom for vivo devices

`device --- VIVO V20 PRO`

**Running OS --- Funtouch OS 13 (based on Android-13)**

Comment: Seems like Vivo phone has no official OEM unlock functionality, therefore users who want to develop a custom ROM just don't buy Vivo phones. Some background is described here: https://www.xda-developers.com/vivo-unofficial-bootloader-unlock-x70-pro-plus/